# java maven import issue: error: package com.google.gson does not exist

Tags: java, maven

I have a new environment, and I'm trying to make a simple java project in IntelliJ containing a ScoreCalculator.java class that will import com.google.gson. This *should* be simple but there's something I'm missing.

I made a fresh maven project (including this dependency in pom.xml), and when I try `javac ScoreCalculator.java` I get:  error: package com.google.gson.stream does not exist

Reading around, I found the jar file where this son-2.8.6.jar file lives (inside my .m2 directory), and I updated my CLASSPATH to be that folder path:

```
Dianes-MBP:java dkaplan$ echo $CLASSPATH
/Users/dkaplan/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.6
```

My pom file has:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>mightier-maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>7</source>
                    <target>7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

My little test program so far has nothing but the imports I'll need:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import com.google.gson.*;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;

public class ScoreCalculator {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

The directory setup looks like this: 
[image: The directory setup looks like this]

But when I try compiling this way I get the error:

```
Dianes-MBP:java dkaplan$ javac ScoreCalculator.java
ScoreCalculator.java:5: error: package com.google.gson.stream does not exist
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
                             ^
ScoreCalculator.java:4: error: package com.google.gson does not exist
import com.google.gson.*;
^
2 errors
```

Note: I also tried the same thing with a fresh Gradle project in IntelliJ and I get the same error from the same command, so I'm thinking there's some setup (or directory organization?) piece I'm missing here.

What else should I do/check?

Comment: I'm running these commands from IntelliJ's terminal window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute these commands from the directory where `ScoreCalculator.java` is present in MacOS.

> `javac -cp /Users/dkaplan/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.6/gson-2.8.6.jar ScoreCalculator.java`
>
> `java -cp /Users/dkaplan/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.6/gson-2.8.6.jar ScoreCalculator`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I see that you use the full path to the jar, whereas I had added only the directory path, not the jar (following an example where only directories were used there). Making that change to the CLASSPATH makes the errors mentioned above go away when I re-attempt javac!  That second command gives an error ("Could not find or load main class ScoreCalculator"), but I may not need that after all?

Comment: From the same directory where the class lives- so it should see it :)
/Users/dkaplan/DianeCodeTests/mightier-maven/src/main/java

Answer (score 0):

use this dependency

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20090211</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I added that to my pom.xml and refreshed my maven window and ran 'Download Sources and Documentation', but when I retry "javac ScoreCalculator.java", the error message is exactly the same. Is there another step I need to make that change fully take effect?

Answer (score 0):

I tried many times but when I used
`mvn clean install`
there was no error.

But when I used
`mvn dependency:tree or mvn dependency:list`
Gson and sprite jars were missing from my project and after a lot of trial and error I was able to fix the issue.

The solution that worked for me was to place the dependencies for GSON and Sprite before any other dependency in the pom.xml inside the dependencies xml tag because eralier I was placing them last.